# How do i make the edges sharp without adding loop cuts?

Tags: subdivision-surface, geometry

Hi I have added a sub surf modifier to my car and the edges have curved and I would like to sharpen them.I have tried to use loop cuts but that causes a slight crease in the geometry. Is there another way of sharpening the edges while keeping geometry smooth.

[image: mesh]

I have tried using edge crease and it has definitely helped, however it only gets rid of part of the curve if that makes sense. There is still a bend visible.

[image]

Comment: Try Edge – Edge Crease, shift+e

Comment: @ Andrei Agache Thank you, it does help, but there is still some curve around the edge.